# Custom images are not responsive on mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS for styling, I have a card that is looking fine on desktop but not on mobile view, images did collapse and are not responsive. Somehow I messed up with the tailwindcss classes. I have attached the code please guide me where I am lagging. Your support

> Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.7/tailwind.min.css"/>

</head>
<body>

<div class="border-2 border-gray-400 bg-white shadow-sm m-0 rounded-2xl my-2 transform hover:scale-105 duration-200 ease-in-out cursor-pointer border-2 border-gray-400 bg-white"
>


    <!-- Vaccinated Sticker End -->

    <div class="col-span-2">
        <div class="space-x-4 flex items-center">
            <!-- Member Image -->
            <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-48 w-40 sm:h-40 sm:w-52">
                <img
                    class="ad-image object-cover max-h-full max-w-full h-full w-full rounded-l-xl"
           
                    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628547274104-fca69938d030?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80"
                    alt=""
                />
            </div>
            <!-- Member Image end-->

            <!-- Right Side area-->
            <div class="flex-initial items-center">
                <div class="my-4 space-y-2">
                    <div class="ad-information text-gray-800 font-bold text-base md:text-lg cursor-pointer pr-1">
                        <!-- Emoji Title-->
                        <div class="flex flex-wrap overflow-hidden">
                         <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628547274104-fca69938d030?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80" class="cursor-pointer w-auto md:h-8 h-4 lg:h-8" />
                            as dfakldjf akljf klajdf klajdf kladjf klsfk
                            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628547274104-fca69938d030?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80" class="cursor-pointer w-auto md:h-8 h-4 lg:h-8" />
                             <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628547274104-fca69938d030?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80" class="cursor-pointer w-auto md:h-8 h-4 lg:h-8" />
                              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628547274104-fca69938d030?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80" class="cursor-pointer w-auto md:h-8 h-4 lg:h-8" />
                               <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628547274104-fca69938d030?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80" class="cursor-pointer w-auto md:h-8 h-4 lg:h-8" />
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628547274104-fca69938d030?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80" class="cursor-pointer w-auto md:h-8 h-4 lg:h-8" />
                        </div>
                        <!-- Emoji Title end-->
                        <!--Simple Title-->
                        <!--Simple Title End-->
                        <span class="ad-price normal-case mt-2 font-semibold mr-3 text-gray-800">$/30 minutes</span>
                        <span class="mr-1 border-r border-gray-300 max-h-0"></span>
                        <!-- Just a separator -->

                        <span class="ad-details text-gray-500 font-medium max-h-0">John Doe</span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="ad-details text-gray-500 font-medium max-h-0">30 Years, Asian</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to start by adding a viewport meta tag in the head of your page, eg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.7/tailwind.min.css"/>    
</head>
```

Maybe we'll need to make some additional edits, but start with this and see how it goes.

More about viewport meta tags:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag